# Celery Beat постоянно пишел в лог ошибок отладочные сообщения

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

Доброго времени!
Только начал осваивать связку Django - Celery - RabbitMQ.

Celery Beat несколько раз в минуту пишет в stderr следующее:

```
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "django_celery_beat_periodictasks"."ident", "django_celery_beat_periodictasks"."last_update" FROM "django_celery_beat_periodictasks" WHERE "django_celery_beat_periodictasks"."ident" = 1; args=(1,)
[2017-12-01 08:32:17,021: DEBUG/MainProcess] (0.000) SELECT "django_celery_beat_periodictasks"."ident", "django_celery_beat_periodictasks"."last_update" FROM "django_celery_beat_periodictasks" WHERE "django_celery_beat_periodictasks"."ident" = 1; args=(1,)
```

В общих настройках проекта DEBUG = False, при запуске воркера уровень логгирования INFO. Пара десятков мегабайт в сутки набегает этого мусора.

Python 3.5.2,
Django 1.11.4,
Celery 4.1,
django-celery-beat 1.1.0,
django-celery-results 1.0.1

*/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf*

```
[program:celery]
command=/opt/venv/bin/celery worker -A proj --loglevel=INFO
directory=/opt/proj
user=www-data
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/opt/proj/logs/celery_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/opt/proj/logs/celery_stderr.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 900
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

*/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celerybeat.conf*

```
[program:djodacelerybeat]
command=/opt/venv/bin/celery -A proj beat --loglevel=INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
directory=/opt/proj
user=www-data
numprocs
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/opt/proj/logs/beat_out.log
stderr_logfile=/opt/proj/logs/beat_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
priority=999
```

Comment: Проверьте дефисы перед loglevel, что-то с ними не так

Comment: @andreymal, с ними всё в порядке. Что касается верхнего конфига, это уже при копипастинге движок оверфлоу подменил, видимо. Но я перепроверил, - всё ок(

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы конфиги были такие, какие они есть на самом деле, без всяких подмен. «Движок оверфлоу» внутри кусков кода сам по себе ничего не меняет.

Comment: @andreymal внутрь "кусков кода" текст попадает после нажатия Ctrl-K, а до этого он просто попадает в поле ввода. Тем не менее отредактировал, чтобы не отвлекало, спасибо. Замечу, что воркер celery в лог не строчит, лишь воркер celery beat, а странный длинный дефис был в конфиге celery, не celery beat.

Comment: Теперь меня смущает, что worker и beat запускается в разных venv. Хотя вряд ли это является причиной проблем с логами

Comment: @andreymal это мой косяк в выпиливании названия проекта прямо или опосредованно. На деле всё, конечно, работает из одного места.

Comment: @andreymal После перезагрузки машины перестал писать DEBUG, только INFO. Но и задачи перестал дёргать :(